# Double integral convergence

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that $q>1$.  Let $U$ be the unit disk. For which $a\in (2,4)$, integral  $$I=\int_U\left[\int_U 1/|1-z \bar w|^a dA(z)\right]^q dA(w)$$ converges. Here $dA(z)$ is the area measure of the unit disk.

Comment: expansion near the pole at $z\bar{w}=1$ suggests the double integral diverges as $\epsilon^{(2-a)q}$ with $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, so divergent for any $a>2$ and $q>0$

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker. No it converges for example if q=3/2 and a=2,1

Answer (score -1):

For $(a-2)q>-1 $ the integral converges.